# Sublime Text: move build window to the right

Tags: sublime-text

In sublime text I would like to move the build window to the right side of the screen. I have seen the buildview package but I could not figure out how to install it.  Could someone help me with how to install it or another method to move the build window to the right side of the screen?

Comment: The buildview package should be available in the [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/).

Comment: I tried installing buildview but it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you press `ctrl+shift+p` there is an item `Disable/Enable buildview for this window` to toggle the activation. Have you tried to change this? Do you use the normal build hotkey or have you added your own keybinding?

Comment: The option is not there for disable/enable. I did create my own keybinding to overide the original build command.

Comment: Then you should add a context to your keybinding. E.g. `{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build", "context": [{"key": "build_fake", "operator":"equal", "operand":true}]},`