# Sublime text: Keep build window open

Tags: sublime-text

In sublime text when I try build my code the build window shows up while it is building but then closes when done. I can't see my output when it does this. How do I keep the build window open?

Comment: Please reply on my below answer. Did you try tips from my answer ? *If it unhelpful I'll just remove it*

Comment: This could also be because you have buildview installed. You could try to disable that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open if by navigating to: `Tools | Build Results | Show Build Results`.

Assign shortcut on it if do it pretty often.

Also this sources may be helpful:

- [Disable build window when building in Sublime Text 2](https://superuser.com/a/538648/268507)
- [SublimeText Tip - Move Build Output Window to the Side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB-Uzc6iHyI)

Comment: What I want is a solution that will automatically keep the build window open without any keyboard shortcut or having to click on the show build results.

Comment: @MarkyPython From the second source you can find how to install `Buildview` plugin as you asked [here](http://superuser.com/q/1051990/268507).  Assign shortcut on `Show Build Results` action once and it will be easy further.

Comment: I have tried to install buildview but that didn't work.

Comment: @MarkyPython What version of ST do you use ?

Comment: I am using version 3

Comment: @MarkyPython Did you override key binding configurations ?

Comment: Which key bindings?

Comment: @MarkyPython At this [source](http://thirtysixthspan.com/posts/useful-sublime-text-3-packages-for-a-rubyist) find it by `BUILDVIEW`

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: @MarkyPython Let it be. I give up.